# Excel VBA How to Execute BAT file in folders in current directory

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble executing a bat file that is located in a folder inside the current directory of excel sheet thats running the macro.

I currently have this.

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & " && Comms.BAT"
```

This works if the BAT file is in the current directory how ever I want it to run from a folder thats located with in the directory eg

Curr Dir\Comms\Comms.BAT

I tried this

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & " && \Comms\Comms.BAT"
```

and this

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\Comms\Comms.BAT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example appears to be using an absolute path (\Comms):

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & " && \Comms\Comms.BAT"
```

Try it with a relative path:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & " && .\Comms\Comms.BAT"
```

**UPDATE**

> ... if I use your example its then trying to execute the batch from the current directory and it need to excute it from cur dir /Comms/

If I understand you correctly, your batch file expects the current working directory to be the directory containing the batch file.  In which case, you have two options:

1. Switch to the directory containing the batch file:

   ```
   Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\Comms && Comms.BAT"
   ```
2. Change your batch file to switch to the correct directory.  You can do this by adding the following line to the top of Comms.BAT:

   ```
   cd /d "%~dp0"
   ```

**UPDATE 2**

If the path containing your workbook can contain spaces, you need to add quotes to your command line, as noted in the answer from AnalystCave.com.  For example:

```
    Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d """ & ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\Comms"" && Comms.BAT"
```

Comment: Thats actually working but its create a issue with my batch which executes an comms.exe file. it works if the batch is executed directly if I use your example its then trying to execute the batch from the current directory and it need to excute it from cur dir /Comms/ folder im not sure if this is a batch or excel issue tho but the command prompt is been set to the current directory think it justs need the extra CD to the comms folder

Comment: I was actually about to post i've sorted the problem by adding the CD to the Batch like your second example but I prefer your first example which is working how I was hoping it would work in the first place thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run """" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Comms\Comms.BAT" & """"
Set wsh = Nothing
```

The additional " are to prevent issues with filenames with spaces.

Comment: Thats sort of working its definatly executing the batch file however inside the batch its runs an exe file that is located inside the current directory which doesnt execute which is having trouble running now because command prompt hasnt changes dir its still set as C:\Users\%USER\Documents>Comms.exe I think the directory needs setting